# French encoded characters

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, pdo, character-encoding

Encodings are not my strongest points...

I am building a site which involves a range of different languages.

The database is storing content in UTF-8.

Content is injected on screen from the db with jQuery and AJAX. The problem is, the response is not correctly encoded.
Français returns as Fran�ais

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the default request in jquery is uft8 and the data is stored in the db in uft-8 and the html page is set to `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">`

Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks,
John

When i request the content directly bypassing the jquery ajax the response is encoded correctly.. as in when no header is set by the browser...

Comment: Is the DB connection charset set to utf-8, eg `SET NAMES utf8`? What does the content-type header look like for the AJAX response? How are you injecting the response into the page?

Comment: Wow! brilliant thank you very much, i did not know about setting that one!: array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")

Comment: This question and answer actually helped me.  Don't know why someone saw fit to downvote it.  Upvoting back to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you should make sure your DB connection charset is also utf-8. This is my goto PDO constructor that sets things up nicely...

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Note the *charset* param as part of the DSN. There's no need to run a `SET NAMES` query unless you're stuck on a PHP version lower than 5.3.6.

Comment: $this->db_con = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=$db_database",
           $db_username,
           $db_password,
           array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$this->db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);    $this->db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);